# How to convert array list to map, matching keys to array value?

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin, arraylist

I have an array list of events, and I would like to convert them to a mutable map where one of the event values (date) is the key, and each key contains only events with that date. Below is an example of my original event list:

```
[Event(name="person 1", desc="hello", date="2021-01-05"), 
 Event(name="person 2", desc="hi", date="2021-01-05"), 
 Event(name="person 3", desc="hi", date="2021-01-08")]
```

By iterating though events and adding the key and events each time, I so far get this result:

```
{2021-01-05=[Event(name="person 1", desc="hello", date="2021-01-05"),
             Event(name="person 2", desc="hi", date="2021-01-05"), 
             Event(name="person 3", desc="hi", date="2021-01-08")],
 2021-01-08=[Event(name="person 1", desc="hello", date="2021-01-05"), 
             Event(name="person 2", desc="hi", date="2021-01-05"), 
             Event(name="person 3", desc="hi", date="2021-01-08")]}
```

The result below is what I need, but I am not sure how I would go about getting it. I've tried filtering the map and iterating again, but just cannot get the desired result. Any help would be appreciated.

```
{2021-01-05=[Event(name="person 1", desc="hello", date="2021-01-05"), 
             Event(name="person 2", desc="hi", date="2021-01-05")],
 2021-01-08=[Event(name="person 3", desc="hi", date="2021-01-08")]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `groupBy` for this:

```
val map = events.groupBy(Event::date).toMutableMap()
```

Comment: Thanks this worked; it gave me the output of a List instead of an ArrayList, but that's fine.